# (T-SQL) How to query an audit table, and find changes between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, audit

The audit table looks like this:

```
Audit ID    VendorID     PaymentType     CreateDateUTC
 999        8048         2               2017-10-30-08:84:24
1000        1234         5               2017-10-31-01:17:34
1001        8048         7               2017-10-31-01:17:45
1002        1234         5               2017-10-31-01:17:53
1003        1234         7               2017-10-31-01:18:23
1004        1234         5               2017-11-01-01:18:45
```

In this example, you can see that say - VendorID 1234 started as PaymentType 5, then had another entry where it's still 5 (the audit table records additional changes not relevant to my query), then it changes to 7, but then back to 5.

**Say I'd want to answer the question: 'Between now and date X, these VendorIDs had a change in PaymentType'.** A bonus would be - this was the previous PaymentType.

Expected Results:

```
VendorID  PaymentType  Prev_PaymentType
8048      7            2
```

So say if I queried between now and 10-31-01:00:00, I'd want it to return VendorID 8048 as having changed (and as a bonus, that it's previous PaymentType was 2), but VendorID 1234 shouldn't show up, since at 2017-10-31-01:00:00 it was a 5, and now is still a 5, despite the intermittent changes.

How would one go about querying the VendorIDs whose payment type changed between 2 dates?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be great explanation if you **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47065050/edit)** your question and add expected results as formatted text please.

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach that my prove useful, using OUTER APPLY. Note that the AuditID column is used as a tie-breaker mostly because the sample data does not have datetime values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a352c/24)

```
CREATE TABLE AuditTable (
      AuditID int
    , VendorID int
    , PaymentType int
    , CreateDateUTC date
);

INSERT INTO AuditTable
      VALUES (999, 8048, 2, '2017-10-30'),
      (1000, 1234, 5, '2017-10-31'),
      (1001, 8048, 7, '2017-10-31'),
      (1002, 1234, 5, '2017-10-31'),
      (1003, 1234, 7, '2017-10-31'),
      (1004, 1234, 5, '2017-11-01');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from AuditTable a
outer apply (
  select top(1) PaymentType, CreateDateUTC
  from AuditTable t
  where a.VendorID = t.VendorID
  and a.CreateDateUTC >= t.CreateDateUTC
  and a.AuditID > t.AuditID
  order by CreateDateUTC DESC, AuditID DESC
  ) oa (PrevPaymentType, PrevDate)
order by
      vendorid 
    , CreateDateUTC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a352c/24/0)**:

```
| AuditID | VendorID | PaymentType | CreateDateUTC | PrevPaymentType |   PrevDate |
|---------|----------|-------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|
|    1000 |     1234 |           5 |    2017-10-31 |          (null) |     (null) |
|    1002 |     1234 |           5 |    2017-10-31 |               5 | 2017-10-31 |
|    1003 |     1234 |           7 |    2017-10-31 |               5 | 2017-10-31 |
|    1004 |     1234 |           5 |    2017-11-01 |               7 | 2017-10-31 |
|     999 |     8048 |           2 |    2017-10-30 |          (null) |     (null) |
|    1001 |     8048 |           7 |    2017-10-31 |               2 | 2017-10-30 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE AuditTable (
    AuditID     INT,
    VendorID    INT, 
    PaymentType INT,    
    CreateDateUTC DATE
    );

INSERT INTO AuditTable VALUES
(999 ,        8048,         2,               '2017-10-30'),
(1000,        1234,         5,               '2017-10-31'),
(1001,        8048,         7,               '2017-10-31'),
(1002,        1234,         5,               '2017-10-31'),
(1003,        1234,         7,               '2017-10-31'),
(1004,        1234,         5,               '2017-11-01');

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CreateDateUTC ORDER BY PaymentType) AS N1

FROM AuditTable
WHERE CreateDateUTC <= '2017-11-02' AND CreateDateUTC >= '2017-10-01'
    ) ,
    MAXP AS(
            SELECT VendorID, PaymentType, CreateDateUTC  
            FROM CTE
            WHERE N1 = (SELECT MAX(N1) FROM CTE) 
        ) 
    SELECT TOP 1 MAXP.VendorID, MAXP.PaymentType AS PaymentType, CTE.PaymentType AS Prev_PaymentType
    FROM MAXP
        JOIN CTE ON CTE.VendorID = MAXP.VendorID;
```

Result:

```
+----------+-------------+------------------+
| VendorID | PaymentType | Prev_PaymentType |
+----------+-------------+------------------+
|     8048 |           7 |                2 |
+----------+-------------+------------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/QZF67770)**

Comment: Thanks, I think miscommunication though:  That would show the current, as well as first payment type.  But, 1.) It doesn't allow for seeing the overall change (or not) from a certain date to now. 2.) It requires entering the VendorID, when the goal is more to enter the date, then get the VendorIDs returned.

Comment: @mmace31 You mean querying by date and get `1234 7 5` and `8048 7 2`?

Comment: No, I think he means he wants everything between 2017-10-31 and now() where a vendor status at the start of the period is different to what it is now.  So 1234 would not be listed.  But 8048 would be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant without using `LEAD()` or `LAG()` but does use `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT() OVER()`.

See this verision work at:[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a352c/20)

```
CREATE TABLE AuditTable (
      AuditID int
    , VendorID int
    , PaymentType int
    , CreateDateUTC date
);

INSERT INTO AuditTable
      VALUES (999, 8048, 2, '2017-10-30'),
      (1000, 1234, 5, '2017-10-31'),
      (1001, 8048, 7, '2017-10-31'),
      (1002, 1234, 5, '2017-10-31'),
      (1003, 1234, 7, '2017-10-31'),
      (1004, 1234, 5, '2017-11-01');
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH
      rowz AS (
                  SELECT *
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VendorID
                                             ORDER BY CreateDateUTC, AuditID) AS lagno
                  FROM AuditTable
            ),
      cte AS (
                  SELECT *
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VendorID, CreateDateUTC
                                             ORDER BY c DESC, span_dt) rn
                  FROM (
                        SELECT  r1.AuditID, r1.VendorID, r1.CreateDateUTC
                              , r1.PaymentType AS prevpaymenttype
                              , r2.PaymentType
                              , COALESCE(r2.CreateDateUTC, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) span_dt
                              , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r1.VendorID, r1.CreateDateUTC, r1.PaymentType) c
                        FROM rowz r1
                        LEFT JOIN rowz r2 ON r1.VendorID = r2.VendorID
                              AND r1.lagno = r2.lagno - 1
                  ) d
            )
SELECT
      AuditID, VendorID, PrevPaymentType, PaymentType, CreateDateUTC
FROM (
      SELECT
            *
      FROM cte
      WHERE ('20171031' BETWEEN CreateDateUTC AND span_dt AND rn = 1)
      OR (CAST(GETDATE() AS date) BETWEEN CreateDateUTC AND span_dt AND rn = 1)
) d
WHERE PaymentType <> PrevPaymentType
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a352c/20/0)**:

```
| AuditID | VendorID | PrevPaymentType | PaymentType | CreateDateUTC |
|---------|----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------|
|     999 |     8048 |               2 |           7 |    2017-10-30 |
```

Comment: Ahhhh I bet that works but, and I'm really sorry I didn't say - I'm on SQL Server 2008, and LEAD/LAG aren't supported until 2012!   That looks amazing though...!

Comment: Blast from the past:  So 1.) This is amazing, 2.) Our audit table is extra annoying, in that there can be entries that don't have anything to do with the payment status changing.  So the 'AND r1.lagno = r2.lagno - 1' part, may not work, as r2.lagno - 1 may be the same payment status, but behind that one (or 2 behind that one) is the actual change we need.   Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi. rather than adding to something that has been accepted, I have added another technique you might find useful based on `outer apply`